# Firefox buggy with impress.js

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, animation, transform

I am trying to create an animation-heavy presentation using [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/). On chrome, its coming out awesome and really smooth. But, when I run it on firefox, the presentation looks really really bad.
Problems -

- Elements which are at the back of the front elements (creating a 3D View) can always be seen merging into the front elements. ( some kind of transparency issues )
- Transition from one slide to another is sluggish. Even their own demo is not as smooth on Firefox as it is on Chrome. ( Their [DEMO](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js) )
- I have put about 30 steps in my presentation, and a lot of times, firefox just crashes completely.

If anyone faced with similar problems with firefox and impress.js and found solutions, please help!

Comment: Can you create a small sample illustrating your issues with Firefox? I've checked your DEMO link on firefox and it runs very smoothly for me on very moderate hardware.

Comment: http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/. It is broken on Firefox  34.0 @ Windows 7 x64

Comment: I created an issue on Firefox bug track, this is probably a browser issue. You can vote it up to increase priority: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1106998

Comment: hey! thanks for prompt replies. you can check my presentation on - http://dosshier.me/information-studies/impress/ . This runs very smoothly on Chrome, but very badly on Firefox. My firefox version is 34.0

Comment: hi, @BenjaminGruenbaum, did you get a chance to look at my presentation link?

Comment: hey, @FagnerBrack! did you get to see the presentation link I shared on firefox? any suggestions?

Comment: What you mean by suggestions? It just doesn't work in Firefox 34.0, there's not much you can do to fix it unless waiting for the next release. Firefox is an evergreen browser, so updates should be faster, if you wonder about breaking for customers while its on the edge, you could do some userAgent sniffing to check for Firefox version 34.0 and disable impress for that userAgent string (I don't know any means for feature detection on css 3D bugs, sorry).